# CSS align 2 img with links and form

Tags: css, image, forms, alignment

Hi I'm creating a menu in html with 1000px that has 2 images, one on the left and other on the right sides of the menu with 40px height, also has a group of links on the left and a search form on the right like this:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div align="left">
        <img src="/img/menu_left.jpg"/>
        <a href="">link 1</a> | 
        <a href="">link 2</a> | 
        <a href="">link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <form>
            <input type="text"/>
            <select>
                <option>opt1</option>
                <option>opt2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <img src="/img/menu_right.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to align all the stuffs horizontally and vertically using css instead of tables.
But my css never do what I want :(

```
.menu {
    width:1000px;
    background-image:url('/img/menu_middle.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#bf2b27;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-family: sans-serif, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

The menu has 1000px and the background image works fine, the links appears on the bottom not in the middle, the form is on the right but one line down and the right menu image appears one more line down after the form.

Please help

Comment: `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right version: http://jsfiddle.net/534J7/

1. Dont use align attribute. It's deprecated.
2. Use floats to align.
3. A trick to align vertically is to set `line-height: = container_height`*. You can also use margins (for images for example).

*Instead of "container_height", write the actual height.

Answer (score 0):

For more clean DOM You can use background-image in left div with padding despite the img src.